# How to get most frequent word or in case of tie first alphabetically, from dictionary.values() Python

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to get the most **frequent** value for each key from a dictionary like:

`{'cars': ['sedan', 'sedan', 'van', 'van'], 'snack': ['chips', 'chips', 'cheetos'], 'computer': ['laptop', 'desktop']}`

However, if there is a **tie** it should return the **first word in value list alphabetically**.

Have already tried `collections.Counter` but that returns arbitrary values if there's a tie. I'm also aware that there are posts that show how to find the most frequent values for dictionaries, but they don't address alphabet ordering in case of a tie.

For instance, the above dictionary should return:

`{'cars': 'sedan', 'snack':'chips', 'computer':'desktop'}`

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried sorting the output of `collections.Counter`?

Comment: Please [edit] in what you've tried so far. It helps for testing answers to the question.

Comment: @wjandrea I haven't tried that, how would that work? My current code doesn't work correctly so I don't think it would be worth posting, I can only figure out how to get it to order when there are no ties.

Comment: posting your attempt, even if bad, doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 3):

This looks simple, but needs a lot of transformations to get the proper result

Using `counter` is the proper way, but you have to sort the items. Note that `most_common` method doesn't work/is pretty useless as using `1` as parameter to limit the number of results can choose the "wrong" entry:

```
{k : collections.Counter(v).most_common(1) for k,v in d.items()}   # no dice!!
```

yields `{'cars': [('sedan', 2)], 'computer': [('desktop', 1)], 'snack': [('chips', 2)]}` which is close to what we want, but it can also pick `'van'` some other time...

Natural sort isn't going to work either, as you need to sort according to number of occurrences (inverted), then alphanumerical key. You need a complex sort key:

```
lambda i : (-i[1],i[0])
```

(`i` is the key/value pair, so `-i[1]` is the opposite number of elements, so highest number comes first, and `i[0]` is the name)

Then, pick the first value, and the first item of the value (discarding the count)

Like this:

```
import collections

d = {'cars': ['sedan', 'sedan', 'van', 'van'], 'snack': ['chips', 'chips', 'cheetos'], 'computer': ['laptop', 'desktop']}

c = {k : sorted(collections.Counter(v).items(),
         key = lambda i : (-i[1],i[0]))[0][0] for k,v in d.items() if v}
```

result:

```
>>> c
{'cars': 'sedan', 'computer': 'desktop', 'snack': 'chips'}
```

Note that `if v` condition protected against the "one list is empty" case (else it would raise an `IndexError` when picking the first element).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something that is *not* a one-liner. One-liners might proof that you are a good coder, but are really bad coding style.

This is the perfect time to write a helper function:

```py
from collections import Counter

def most_common(items):
    # Protect against empty input
    if not items:
        return None

    # This does the actual computing
    counter = Counter(items)

    # Initialize the result variables
    result, max_count = counter.most_common(1)[0]

    # most_common are sorted, so we can stop once the count is not the max count
    for elem, count in counter.most_common():
        if count != max_count:
            break
        # replace with alphabetically better result
        result = min(result,elem)

    return result

inp = {'cars': ['sedan', 'sedan', 'van', 'van'], 'snack': ['chips', 'chips', 'cheetos'], 'computer': ['laptop', 'desktop']}

results = {key: most_common(val) for key, val in inp.items()}
print(results)
# {'cars': 'sedan', 'snack': 'chips', 'computer': 'desktop'}
```

Comment: No, the problem is that he changed his specification from 'highest alphabetical' to 'lowest alphabetical'. My result was correct, until then. Replacing `result = max(result,elem)` with `result = min(result,elem)` should adjust that.
I know that `counter.most_common()` doesn't return anything sorted, that's why I iterate and replace with alphabetically better result.