# How to sort list, first by frequency of items, then by the value of the item

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, frequency

I need to take a python list of numbers and find the most common element but if there is a tie, I need the element with the smallest value. For example, if the most common element in a list is a tie between 3 and 4, I need to get the value 3 because it is the smaller of the two.

Comment: The obvious place to start is `sorted` and a `key`. Have you gotten here yet? We will help you if you can tell us what you've tried and what hasn't worked. Thanks

Comment: Thanks I figured it out using the sorted and key thing. I just realized that I could sort the list using list.sort() before sorting using the key and it made it work.

Comment: Related: [How to get most frequent word or in case of tie first alphabetically, from dictionary.values\(\) Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56331616/4518341)

Comment: @Prune I had made an attempt and run into a problem, but when I tried to post it, Stack Overflow was giving me some sort of error (I think the code made it think it was formatted improperly or something). That's why I had to remove it from my post.

Answer (score 2):

```
import collections

x = [2,4,3,2,6,4,4,4,3,3,3]

counts = collections.Counter(x)

new_list = sorted(x, key=lambda i: (-counts[i],i))

print(new_list[0])
```

output:3

There, your item always in new_list[0]

Comment: Your key is incomplete it should be `(-counts[x], x)`

Comment: It works just as i wrote, while your option causes syntax error

Comment: It works because `sorted` is stable and the first `3` happens to appear before the first `4` in your unsorted list. Try it again with `x= [2,4,3,2,6,4,4,4,3,3,3]`. Result is `4`.